# Why schema of createable checking failed when the user clearly has the permission

Tags: apex, unit-test

I had this very simple code in my class:

```
  Interaction intToInsert = new Interaction();

  if (Interaction.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable()) {
    insert intToInsert;
  }
```

When I run unit test against this class, the line of `insert intToInsert` is not run. Initially we thought it must be the permission issue so we tried to fix this. However, at last, we found out out by simply commenting out this line: `if (Interaction.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable())`, the code can pass.

The insert is definitely executed well since in the unit test we checked the record is created and the value of the created record's fields are correct. We also checked the code coverage and everything looks perfect.

So since the insert can be executed well without any issue I would assume the permission is correct (actually we checked the permission set multiple times as well and it does grant the create access). And that line should have nothing to do with field access or triggers or anything else, why is that line failing?

**Edit**

Add some settings in unit test as requested:
User setup:

```
User apiUser = TestUtil.createTestUser(
    new Map<String, Object>{
      'FirstName' => 'APIUserTestForInteraction',
      'ProfileId' => p.Id,
      'UserRoleId' => role.Id
    }
  );
  insert apiUser;

  // Assign Case related PS on API User
  List<String> psNames = new List<String>{
    'Chat_Read_Write',
    'Interaction_Read_Write',
    'API_Access_Twilio',
    'API_Only',
    'Enforce_mTLS'
  };
  List<PermissionSet> psList = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM PermissionSet
    WHERE Name IN :psNames
  ];
  List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
  for (PermissionSet ps : psList) {
    psaList.add(TestUtil.createPSAssignment(apiUser.id, ps.Id));
  }
  insert psaList;
```

Running test:

```
System.runAs(usr) {
  InteractionContextService.doPost(intContext);
}
```

Comment: Are permissions defined via perm set group or some other approach?

Comment: @PhilW I created a test user in the unit test. The permissions are granted via profile and permission sets

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show the basic flow of your unit test, including the user setup and usages of Test.start/stopTest plus System.runAs? Thanks.

Comment: @PhilW updated as per requested

Comment: Not sure what the error is, but you shouldn't need to use System.runAs, as that only enforces sharing - not CRUD or FLS, which is what you're checking with the isCreateable() call. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm